# RoR: how can I search only microposts with a certain attribute?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now in app/views/microposts/home.html.erb I have..

```
<% form_tag purchases_path, :method => 'get', :id => "products_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<% form_tag sales_path, :method => 'get', :id => "sales_search" do %>
      <p>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
```

and then in micropost.rb I have

```
scope :purchases, where(:kind => "purchase")
  scope :sales, where(:kind => "sale")

 def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
```

and then finally in the microposts_controller.rb I have

```
def home

    @microposts=Micropost.all
    @purchases=@microposts.purchases
    @sales=@microposts.sales

  end
```

Right now I am getting an error saying undefined local variable or method `purchases_path' and it does the same for sales_path.

What I want to be able to do is search only some of the microposts instead of all of them. In my micropost table I have a column called kind which can be either "purchase" or "sale". How can I change these three pieces of code so that one search searches through and displays results for only those microposts with the kind "purchase". And then the other searches through and displays results for only those microposts with the kind "sale"

this question (on another post) has a bounty with 50 rep at [RoR: how can I search only microposts with a specific attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575140/ror-how-can-i-search-only-microposts-with-a-specific-attribute)

Comment: why do you use old syntax instead of `where` clauses?

Comment: I was going off of this tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form. maybe that is my problem

Answer (score 1):

You might try this.

Your model:

```
class Micropost
  # ...
  scope :purchase_only, where(:kind => "purchase")
  # ...
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      self.purchase_only.find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      self.purchase_only
    end
  end
end
```

But, this stuff looks very strange to me.

E.g.: You should remove the `.find(...)`, this finder will be deprecated with Rails 4.

Comment: you are right. I updated my question in accordance with rails 3. But your answer didn't work :(. It gave a routing error, no method GET / [microposts]. Can you look at my edits and see what I am doing wrong?